# .htaccess 301 not mapping subdirectory assets

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-301

I had a WordPress instance hosted on a subdirectory on a domain. I have now changed the domain and moved the WordPress setup to the root of a new domain.

I have set up .htaccess on the old domain root directory as follows.

```
Redirect 301 /subdirectory https://newdomain.com/
```

And it's working pretty well. But for some reason, the assets in the subdirectory chain are throwing 403 forbidden. The following pattern ends up with 403.

https://olddomain.com/subdirectory/wp-content/uploads/1.jpg

What I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: When you have uploaded the database, have you changed the URL in database?

Comment: Yes, its all changed in the database. The problem is with the redirect pattern in old domain as it is not making a redirect for assets in subdirectory tree like in the example above.

Comment: To change the URL what you have done because after the query this issue shouldn't become.

Comment: _“ends up with 403”_ - before or after being redirected? Is this all your .htaccess contains?

Comment: @CBroe It was being cached by a firewall in place, I have removed the cache and its back to functioning as expected.